# What's Julia's equivalent of R's replicate and rep?

Tags: julia

In R `replicate(n, expr)` repeatedly run the `expr` expression `n` times in contrast to `rep(value, n)` which repeats the `value` `n` times.

What's Julia's equivalent of R's `replicate` and `rep`?

Eg. in R

`rep(1:3, 3)` yields `c(1:3, 1:3, 1:3)`

and `replicate(3, runif(1))` generates 3 random numbers from the uniform distribute (i.e. it ran `runif(1)` 3 times.

Comment: Is `fill(value, n)` what you mean by "repeats the value n times"?

Comment: not sure what you really need, could you write a simple example? but it seems `repeat` is the closest one: `replicate`->`repeat(1:5, inner=(1,5))`, and `rep`-> `repeat(1:5, outer=(2,1))`.

Comment: @Gnimuc added R examples

Comment: You can also use an iterator, e.g., `ncycle` from [`IterTools.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/IterTools.jl)
or `repeated` from `Base.Iterators`. This way you do not have to actually create the larger structure which can save you memory allocations if it is not needed.

Comment: I never use R, so from a layman's perspective, `rep(v,n)` is equivalent to `repeat(v, inner=(1,n))` and `replicate` is equivalent to for-loops or array comprehensions `[rand() for i = 1:n]`.

Answer (score 6):

I may be late to the party, but here is some R and Julia code that combines suggestions from the comments:

```
# R version 3.5.1 of rep function
> rep(1:3, 3)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

# Julia version 1.0.0 of repeat function
julia> repeat(1:3, 3)
9-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3
 1
 2
 3

# R version 3.5.1 for replicate function
> replicate(3, runif(1))
[1] 0.3849424 0.3277343 0.6021007

# Julia version 1.0.0 of an array comprehension
julia> [rand() for i in 1:3]
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.8076220876500786
 0.9700908450487538
 0.14006111319509862
```